# Which version of Artifactory resolves vulnerability CVE-2022-22965?

Tags: spring, artifactory

What version of JFrog Artifactory do I need to update to to mitigate the vulnerability in CVE-2022-22965?

I'm using version 7.18.12 but I'm not sure if that is new enough.

Answer (score 1):

JFrog DevOps platform is not vulnerable to SpringShell (CVE-2022-22965) or the recent RCE vulnerability in Spring Cloud Function (CVE-2022-22963). you can find more info about it [here](https://jfrog.com/blog/springshell-zero-day-vulnerability-all-you-need-to-know/).